# Как влияет шифрование диска Linux на скорость работы и производительность системы

Tags: linux

При установке какой-либо Linux (например Ubuntu или Kali), установщик предлагает установить шифрование диска.

Как скажется шифрование на скорости работы системы?, будет ли Linux использовать больше ресурсов компьютера и будет ли это заметно?

Comment: если есть дополнительная операция, то конечно это скажется на скорости работы. Но современные процессоры поддерживают многие примитивы шифрования "из коробки", поэтому сильно не должно проседать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В большей степени это будет влиять на старт ОС, т.к. данные зашифрованного диска необходимо расшифровать перед чтением. Лично у меня это не вызывало никаких проблем, однако есть вероятность столкнутся с проблемами при востановлении системы, если что-то пошло не так.

Если у Вас нет необходимости хранить большие объемы супер секретного содержания можно ограничиться шифрованием директории пользователя (при необходимости)

Еще не приходилось сталкиваться со специалистами, которые рекомендуют шифровать диск. Если есть желание что-то спрятать или ограничить доступ используют более ухищренные способы. Например `LVM` на нескольких физических дисках с доп плюшками

Comment: *Еще не приходилось сталкиваться со специалистами, которые рекомендуют шифровать диск* - достаточно просто почитать любой репортаж про посадку за репост и увидеть в комментарии от приглашенного специалиста именно это

Answer (score 0):

Так или иначе влияет на произодительность дисковой подсистемы, процессора и расход памяти. Как именно влияет от выбранного алгоритма шифрования, поддержки его на аппаратном уровне, выбранного варианта шифрования: определнный раздел шифруется, весь диск, несколько дисков.